# Can't join to room through Unity's Matchmaking system on the Internet

Tags: unity, android, unity-networking, pc

It works perfectly when I try to connect **locally from my editor to my running build**.

But after I start the **server on my Android**, and try to connect to it **from my editor**, it **time outs**:

[image]

As you can see, it **finds the match**, and then **tries to join**, but it can't.

If I try to do it from a **build**, the log says the following:

```
Log: cannot connect after {10} attempt address {::ffff:127.0.0.1:7777}
ClientDisconnected due to error: Timeout
```

Why does it tries **localhost**, when I obviously **use the Matchmaking system**?

When I tried it on 2 Android devices, the same happened.

Ps.: I know that it's going to be depracated, I just want to use it during a short term gift.

Thanks in advance!

Starting Matchmaker in a **Start:**

```
networkManager.StartMatchMaker();
networkManager.matchMaker.baseUri = new System.Uri("https://eu1-mm.unet.unity3d.com");
```

When the **MatchScene ("Battle") is loaded:**

```
if (this.isHost)
{
    networkManager.StartHost();
}
else
{
    networkManager.StartClient();
}
```

And the **Play button's handle**: (still same component)

```
public void Play()
{
    networkManager.matchMaker.ListMatches(0, 1, string.Empty, true, 0, 0, OnMatchList);
}

void OnMatchList(bool success, string extendedInfo, List<MatchInfoSnapshot> matches)
{
    if (matches.Count == 0)
    {
        networkManager.matchMaker.CreateMatch("match", 2, true, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, 0, 0, OnMatchCreate);
    }
    else
    {
        networkManager.matchMaker.JoinMatch(matches[0].networkId, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, 0, 0, OnMatchJoined);
    }
}

void OnMatchCreate(bool success, string extendedInfo, MatchInfo matchInfo)
{
    this.isHost = true;
    this.networkId = matchInfo.networkId;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Battle");
}

void OnMatchJoined(bool success, string extendedInfo, MatchInfo matchInfo)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Battle");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't fix it under a day, I gave up and switched to **PUN**, which took me only like 5 hours.

And it was instantly working.

I used these sites:

https://blog.photonengine.com/dev-story-tanks-multiplayer/

https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/getting-started/pun-intro

Comment: This answer would be even better if it described what steps you had to take to implement your PUN solution.

Comment: Updated the answer with the sources I based my refactor on.